# Why do I get error 0x80070004 when trying to update to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1-upgrade

So, I'm trying to update Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 via the Windows Store, but every time I attempt to, the update downloads properly, but then I get the error:

> Windows 8.1
>   This app wasn't installed - view details

When I click on it, it says:

> Something happened and the Windows 8.1 could not be installed. Please try again. Error code: 0x80070004
>     `Try again` `Cancel Install`

What does this mean? A quick Google search yields nothing.

I have tried rebooting, clearing the store cache, and resetting Windows Update. All Windows Updates were installed. I have tried using a different administrator account, and it does not work.

---

A quick `chkdsk` scan shows no errors.

---

A SFC scan now shows no errors.

---

I found the error log!

http://pastebin.com/BXZEsejm

Why is the registry corrupt?

---

DISM Results

```
Checking System Update Readiness.


Summary:
Operation: Detect and Repair 
Operation result: 0x0
Last Successful Step: Entire operation completes.
Total Detected Corruption:  0
Total Repaired Corruption:  0
    CSI Store Metadata refreshed:   True

Total Operation Time: 1405 seconds.
```

Comment: The [0x80070004 error](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0x80070004) is "ERROR_TOO_MANY_OPEN_FILES". Not overly helpful up front. :)  What have you tried already?  For example: Have you tried restarting and trying the update again?

Comment: It's not be that literal. ;) It's more likely too many open file by that one process (the updater).  If you've tried rebooting (you haven't said what you've tried yet), also try [resetting Windows Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058), and [reset the Store cache](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13133-store-cache-clear-windows-8-a.html).

Comment: @techie007 I have now tried all of those and am still getting the same error.

Comment: If you haven't already, do some disk checks.  From here on, I suggest you Edit your question and update it to include what you've tried, and what the results were.  Hopefully that'll help someone recognize what's going on without suggesting things you've already tried.  But that's a weird situation for sure, an di don't have any specific answers.  If the disk checks come up clean, it might be worth contacting MS' support about.

Comment: @JeffreyLin have you moved any user profile to other disk rather than default location of `C:/`? If yes most probably this is the culprit in your case as many other user have confirmed this. From [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05f77774-f633-444e-82c3-1567517cec67/getting-error-0x80070004-when-i-try-to-install-81?forum=w8itproinstall) and [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1846480/windows-pro-update-fails-install.html#.)

Comment: @JeffreyLin Also you can try with a reset of your windows 8 or use [this method](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/4275-user-profiles-relocate-another-partition-disk.html). Of course you will loose your data and apps if you reset so backup them before doing so.

Comment: @avirk I had linked `.minecraft` in %APPDATA% to a different partition. After removing that, I still have this error. I don't really want to reset Windows unless I have to. Also, log has been updated.

Comment: @JeffreyLin not to remove that folder just link it back there where it should be and that is `c:/` also if it doesn't help you then you have to reset the pc or try 7-8 times as some users reported they have success by that.

Comment: Do you have a rollback log  `$windows.~bt\Sources\Rollback`   The problem will be found near the end, uninstall offending app and try upgrade again.

Comment: I have gone through the [process of upgrading my XP to win 8](http://reviewofweb.com/windows8/upgrade-windows-xp-to-windows-8/) last week which went pretty smooth. Before you started the upgrade, did you download and installed the updates meant for Windows 8? Not installing those can be one of the reasons why you see the error. 

Initially, I was not able to locate 8.1 in the store, once I installed all updates for Win 8, 8.1 was available.

Comment: From your log, the user `Jeffrey` seems to have a corrupt profile. Try to delete that account (back up any data there first).

Comment: @avirk the problem is not with moving any individual profile, the problem is with the `Users` directory — it contains quite a few system files and can’t be relocated

Comment: @kinokijuf System files, you said? Could I pinpoint which? If so, how?

Comment: The files in `\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WinX`, for example.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/05f77774-f633-444e-82c3-1567517cec67/getting-error-0x80070004-when-i-try-to-install-81?forum=w8itproinstall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have problems in Windows 8. There is no point in trying to upgrade to 8.1
without fixing them first and verifying that "sfc /scannow" passes without errors and
also that Windows Update is functional and can fully patch your Windows installation.

Some utilities that could help you check for problems are :

- [Use the inbox Deployment Image Servicing and Management (DISM) tool
  to fix corruption errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947821#dism).
  This creates a log file that could help us if posted.
- [Windows Repair (All In One)](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html)
- Disable any third-party antivirus or security suite.

If none of them helps, [Do a Repair Install of Windows 8 without Losing Anything](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26095-repair-install-windows-8-a.html).

The next step is to verify if your user profile got corrupted.
Follow the instructions in the article
[How to fix corrupt user profile in windows 8](http://mywindows8.org/fix-corrupt-profile-in-windows-8/#.UP5fjwaPDC0.scoopit)
to create a new administrator profile and see if it can do better than your old account.

If nothing helps, my remaining advice is to look up the article
[How to refresh, reset, or restore your PC](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc).
If the problem is recent, try first to restore to a system restore point that
dates from before the problem appeared. If that doesn't help, then try a Refresh,
with a Reset as the last possible action. If Reset does not work, reformat the disk
and reinstall Windows 8 from DVD or USB.

In all cases, ensure before starting that all your data is safely backed up.

---

Once  "sfc /scannow" and Windows Update pass without errors,
follow the steps outlined in the article :
[Fix: Your Windows 8.1 install couldn’t be completed error](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/your-windows-8-1-install-couldnt-be-completed).

In a nutshell, the instructions are to open a Command Prompt as administrator,
then enter :

```
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
```

Then browse to the `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` folder and delete all the files and folders inside (restart if in use).

Then enter the following commands :

```
net start wuauserv
net start bits
```

Now open the Windows Store and try the upgrading process all over again.

---

If you still have errors with the Store, some advice :

- Disable all security products
- In Command Prompt (cmd) Run as Administrator, execute `WSReset.exe` to reset the Store

Comment: I see that sfc now works, so I added a second part to my answer. Your comments are welcome.

Comment: See the article [How to Install Windows 8.1 Update When Missing From Store](http://voices.yahoo.com/how-install-windows-81-update-missing-from-12452995.html). The best advice there is installing KB2871389, but you should do Windows Update for ALL mandatory AND optional updates before attempting 8.1. See also [Why can't I find the update in the Store?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-can-t-find-update-store).

Comment: These are useless, no point. Have you tried the links in my above comment?

Comment: I believe the problem started a long time ago. I had created a new user profile for some reason, and then migrated all my user data. I changed the user profile name and then messed with the stuff in the registry. Could this be what is causing the problem?

Comment: Probably in c:\windows\setuperr.log, please post if not empty. Have you tried (1) stopping all security products, (2) in cmd run as admin run `WSReset.exe`, (3) another administrator account. See also [this link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/update-from-windows-8-tutorial). Have you maybe displaced your user profile from C: to another disk using a symbolic link?

Comment: Deleting my user profile did the trick. I was due for a user cleanup anyway, so that's alright. Currently rebooting, this is good.